# Why arent trigonometric functions considered a polynomial?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, polynomials

I know its a very naive question, so please excuse me. But i was wondering that why the function $cos(x)=0$ is not a polynomial function? Is it a pure trigonometric function?

Comment: That's not a function but an equation.

Comment: Polynomials are things like $3x^2 +x$ or $5x^17 + 4x^3 + 4$. A sum of powers.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a polynomial is a function of the form $$p(x) := \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k x^k$$ where $n \geq 0, \alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{K}$.
See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial).

$cos(x) = 0$ is not a functions, its an equation. The function $cos$ cannot be expressed in the above form.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a polynomial-if such a terminology as "closest to" is sound-by which we can write a trigonometric function such as $\cos x$ is a Taylor series:
$$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots$$
Any chance you saw something like this and got the idea?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a set of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). This set does not include summation operator, which we can use to link "any" function to a sum of polynomials (Taylor series), goniometrics (Fourier series) and inherently to a sum of exponentials (Euler's identity). If not stated otherwise, we usually bound ourselves with elementary functions, therefore we cannot consider a goniometric function to be a polynomial.